# fetching tables name from database by query in php file

Tags: php

> Blockquote

sir i want to fetch all the table's name and information about all table as total no. of field etc  with the help of single query in php file .i am using phpmyadmin as mysql please tell me how can i do it.

thanks

Comment: **SHOW TABLES** query

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from information_schema.TABLES
```

You can also check :

```
select * from information_schema.COLUMNS
```